Mantine Flex Stack and Image -- image not showing
I want to render a preview image horizontally next to two vertically stacked inputs. If I was using simple CSS, I would do it like this:


#container {
  display: flex;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
}
#container img {
  object-fit: contain;
}
#inputs {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
<div id="container">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/17/200/300">
  <div id="inputs">
    <input name="url" value="https://picsum.photos/id/17/200/300">
    <input name="alt" value="Image alt goes here">
  </div>
</div>



(Ideally I'd also like not to specify the height of #container, but rather have it be only just as high as the height of the combined inputs.)
I'm trying to achieve a similar layout using Mantine components. This is what I have ATM:
<Flex>
    <Image src="https://picsum.photos/id/17/200/300" />
    <Stack flex="1">
        <TextInput label="Image url" value="https://picsum.photos/id/17/200/300" />
        <TextInput label="Image alt goes here" />
    </Stack>
</Flex>

But the image ends up with a width of 0:

How can I fix this?

It seems works on Chrome, but it doesn't come out on firefox. Is the <Image> from @mantine/core?

@NINE Yes.

Firefox
flex: 0 seems to have a bad relationship with firefox.
If you remove flex: 0, the original proportion of the image will be expressed. You can adjust the size as you want.
* add: If you use flex:0 and width: n%, the width of the image is 0. Other units such as px, em, and rem are possible.

Chrome
Even if flex: 0 is set, the image comes out well.
* add: If you use flex:0 and width: n%, the width of the image not changed. Other units such as px, em, and rem are possible.

